# sws_scale YUV --> RGB distorted image

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, yuv, libavcodec

I want to convert `YUV420P` image (received from `H.264` stream) to `RGB`, while also resizing it, using `sws_scale`.
The size of the original image is `480 × 800`. Just converting with same dimensions works fine.
But when I try to change the dimensions, I get a distorted image, with the following pattern:

- changing to `481 × 800` will yield a distorted B&W image which looks like it's cut in the middle
- `482 × 800` will be even more distorted
- `483 × 800` is distorted but in color
- `484 × 800` is ok (scaled correctly).

Now this pattern follows - scaling will only work fine if the difference between divides by 4.

Here's a sample code of the way that I decode and convert the image. All methods show "success".

```
int srcX = 480;
int srcY = 800;
int dstX = 481; // or 482, 483 etc
int dstY = 800;

AVFrame* avFrameYUV = avcodec_alloc_frame();
avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)avFrameYUV, decoded_yuv_frame, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, srcX , srcY);

AVFrame *avFrameRGB = avcodec_alloc_frame();

AVPacket avPacket;
av_init_packet(&avPacket);
avPacket.size = read; // size of raw data
avPacket.data = raw_data; // raw data before decoding to YUV

int frame_decoded = 0;
int decoded_length = avcodec_decode_video2(g_avCodecContext, avFrameYUV, &frame_decoded, &avPacket);
int size = dstX * dstY * 3;

struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(srcX, srcY, SOURCE_FORMAT, dstX, dstY, PIX_FMT_BGR24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)avFrameRGB, rgb_frame, PIX_FMT_RGB24, dstX, dstY);
sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, avFrameYUV->data, avFrameYUV->linesize, 0, srcY, avFrameRGB->data, avFrameRGB->linesize);

// draws the resulting frame with windows BitBlt
DrawBitmap(hdc, dstX, dstY, rgb_frame, size);

sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);
```

Comment: feel free to post a bug at https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/newticket

Comment: In sws_getContext() function you are passing as parameter the format identifier PIX_FMT_BGR24 instead of PIX_FMT_RGB24 as you do in avpicture_fill

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a bitmap image, the width of image MUST be multiple of 4.

So you have to change width like 480, 484, 488, 492 ...

Here is method to change to multiple of 4

```
#define WIDTHBYTES(bits) (((bits) + 31) / 32 * 4)

void main()
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmFileHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmInfoHeader;

    // load image
    // ...

    // when you use the method, put parameter like this.
    int tempWidth = WIDTHBYTES(width * bmInfoHeader.biBitCount);
}
```

I hope you solve the problem.

Comment: No, it does not have to be a multiple of 4. The code snippet is even farther from the whole thing as it demos how to align up width, it's irrelevant to the question.