# FFmpeg decode and convert RGB sws_scale error

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, yuv, libavcodec

I have a problem with my code.

I want convert YUV to RGB, but `sws_scale` returns 0 always and data is filled 00000000..NULL

I tried googling, but I could not find any problems.

Do I need AVPicture or QImage? Can anyone point out my problem?

```
 pVFrame = av_frame_alloc();
 while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) == 0) {
        if (packet.stream_index == VSI) {
            if (bool res = avcodec_send_packet(pVideoCodecCtx, &packet)) {
                printf("avcodec_send_packet failed %d %d %d\n", res, AVERROR(EINVAL), AVERROR(ENOMEM));
            }
            avcodec_receive_frame(pVideoCodecCtx, pVFrame);

            AVFrame* YUV_frame = Con_yuv_YUV420P(pVFrame);
            QFrame->push(Con_yuv_RGB(YUV_frame));
        }
    }
}


AVFrame* Con_yuv_RGB(AVFrame* YUV_frame)
{
AVFrame* RGBFrame = av_frame_alloc();

SwsContext* sws_Context = NULL;
sws_Context = sws_getCachedContext(sws_Context, YUV_frame->width, YUV_frame->height, pVideoCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
    YUV_frame->width, YUV_frame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (sws_Context == NULL) {
    return false;
}
result = sws_scale(sws_Context, YUV_frame->data, YUV_frame->linesize, 0, (int)YUV_frame->height, RGBFrame->data, RGBFrame->linesize);
if (result < 0)
{
    return false;
}
av_frame_unref(YUV_frame);
if (RGBFrame == NULL) {
    av_frame_unref(RGBFrame);
    return false;
}

sws_freeContext(sws_Context);

return RGBFrame;
```

What is the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJHnR.png)

Reference link -     https://gist.github.com/nakaly/11eb992ebd134ee08b75e4c67afb5703,

http://codefromabove.com/2014/10/ffmpeg-convert-rgba-to-yuv/,

[sws_scale YUV --> RGB distorted image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494546/sws-scale-yuv-rgb-distorted-image),

https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/464977-sws_scale-problems/

https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/group__libsws.html#gae531c9754c9205d90ad6800015046d74

ADD:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usOB7.png)

before convert. It has to fill the buffer.

```
RGBFrame->width = YUV_frame->width;     RGBFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32;
RGBFrame->height = YUV_frame->height;
int result = av_frame_get_buffer(RGBFrame, 32);
if (result != 0)    return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ffmpeg documentation covers it:

https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/group__lavu__frame.html#gac700017c5270c79c1e1befdeeb008b2f

> AVFrame* av_frame_alloc   (   void        )
>
> Allocate an AVFrame and set its fields to default values.
>
> The resulting struct must be freed using av_frame_free().
>
> Returns An AVFrame filled with default values or NULL on failure. Note
>   this only allocates the AVFrame itself, not the data buffers. Those
>   must be allocated through other means, e.g. with av_frame_get_buffer()
>   or manually.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/group__lavu__frame.html#ga6b1acbfa82c79bf7fd78d868572f0ceb

> int av_frame_get_buffer   (   AVFrame *   frame, int  align  )         Allocate
>   new buffer(s) for audio or video data.
>
> The following fields must be set on frame before calling this
>   function:
>
> format (pixel format for video, sample format for audio) width and
>   height for video nb_samples and channel_layout for audio This function
>   will fill AVFrame.data and AVFrame.buf arrays and, if necessary,
>   allocate and fill AVFrame.extended_data and AVFrame.extended_buf. For
>   planar formats, one buffer will be allocated for each plane.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! with I saw your other answers. You are my idol.
So I add my code Width, height, and format. and av_frame_get_buffer looks like working right way. But I can't sure it is all complete convert RGB.
How can I check it's RGBFrame?
when debugging Frame->data has Invalid characters in string.
I add capture image at question

Comment: `data` is a pointer to a pointer, so make sure you are looking at RGBFrame->data[0]. And since pixel values can be anything 0-255 per channel, its not possible to have an invalid byte.

Comment: RGBFrame->data [0]  has strange data.. It's mean to convert failed? Please more explanation.

Comment: please expand. what is strange about it?

Comment: In debugging, RGBFrame->data[0] shows me "Invalid characters in string."
I guess this convert successfully. Is this right?

Comment: I cant say without seeing the data, But because every possible byte value is valid in a raw RGB buffer, there is literally no such thing as "Invalid characters". I don't know what that message if from, but what ever it is, it doesn't know the format of the data it is parsing.

Comment: I added capture image in question. could you check it please?  jpeg decode frame and I will try to H.264 after solve the problem.

Comment: Because its not a string. it's an image. Your IDE is trying to parse it as text, and it's failing because it's not text. There is literally no such thing as Invalid characters in a raw RGB buffer. Ignore that message

Comment: I understood. Thanks a lot. It's so much helpful.